# Snowflake - Finding Expiration Date in query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like the one shown below. Now I need to add a new filed called Expiration date based on these rows. Since the first row ABCD is repeated I need to add expiration date of 2/28/2021 and for 2nd and 3rd row 1/1/9999.
How can I browse through the rows (via snowflake function) in order to calculate expiration date?

[image]

Comment: The expiration dates "2/28/2021 and 1/1/9999' are the values that should be set for the new field "Expiration date"?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for basic SCD2 functionality. Here is the query:

```
    with CTE as (
    select 'ABCD' as TypeName, 200 as Amount, '2021-01-01'::DATE as ValidFrom union all
    select 'b1234' as TypeName, 300 as Amount, '2021-02-01'::DATE as ValidFrom union all
    select 'ABCD' as TypeName, 150 as Amount, '2021-03-01'::DATE as ValidFrom
    )
    select TypeName, Amount, ValidFrom, 
      nvl(dateadd(DAY, -1, lead(ValidFrom) over (partition by TypeName order by ValidFrom)), '9999-01-01'::DATE) as ExpirationDate
    from CTE
    order by ValidFrom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to physically add that row or can the row be virtual?

**physical**

1. Alter table, add column
2. Run date statement to update rows based on there being another row newer by Typename

Alternatively do a CTAS

**virtual**
Create a view over the table using the Window function to track changes

```
  select * 
   , coalesce(lead(ValidFrom) over (partition by TypeName order by ValidFrom)
   , cast('9999-12-31' as date)) as ValidTo
```

from CTE;